# How to install DBeaver's sample database?

Tags: dbeaver

How do I get DBeaver to create its sample database after declining its first offer (without re-installing or deleting `%APPDATA%\DBeaverData\workspace6`) ?

Example screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. You can update your DBeaver version. You can find the "Create Sample Database" under the "Help" button. (Image from DBeaver 21.3.0, will be released soon).

[image: Create Sample database]

2. Or you can just specify the way to the sample database directly in the new SQLite connection. Usually, you can find Chinook.db in the %APPDATA%\DBeaverData\workspace6. For me it was "workspace6.metadata.metadata\sample-database-sqlite-1" path.